# Mybatis interceptor execution order

Tags: java, mybatis, interceptor

I define two interceptors in *mybatis-config.xml*.

```
<plugins>
    <plugin interceptor="cn.common.interceptor.DbInterceptor"/>
    <plugin interceptor="cn.common.interceptor.MybatisInterceptor"/>
</plugins>
```

Implementation of two interceptors.

```
@Intercepts(value = {
        @Signature (type=Executor.class, method="update", args = { MappedStatement.class, Object.class })})
public class DbInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    private Properties properties;

    @Override
    public Object intercept(Invocation invocation) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("db interceptor invoke");
        return invocation.proceed();
    }

    @Override
    public Object plugin(Object target) {
        return Plugin.wrap(target, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void setProperties(Properties properties) {
        this.properties = properties;
    }
}


@Intercepts({
        @Signature(type = Executor.class, method = "update", args = {MappedStatement.class, Object.class})})
public class MybatisInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    private Properties properties;

    @Override
    public Object intercept(Invocation invocation) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("mybatis interceptor invoke");
        return invocation.proceed();
    }

    @Override
    public Object plugin(Object target) {
        return Plugin.wrap(target, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void setProperties(Properties properties) {
        this.properties = properties;
    }

}
```

The **MybatisInterceptor** was first executed after I perform an update method.

But I want **DbInterceptor** interceptors to execute first, what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `MyBatis` the latter plugin will be executed first,so I think you just need to change the config order of the plugins:

Change from

```
<plugins>
    <plugin interceptor="cn.common.interceptor.DbInterceptor"/>
    <plugin interceptor="cn.common.interceptor.MybatisInterceptor"/>
</plugins>
```

To

```
<plugins>
    <plugin interceptor="cn.common.interceptor.MybatisInterceptor"/>
    <plugin interceptor="cn.common.interceptor.DbInterceptor"/>
</plugins>
```

More details can be found at **[CSDN](https://blog.csdn.net/babys/article/details/50586735)**